# What is the implication of the warning in the fontspec manual with respect to babel and LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, languages, babel

In the `fontspec` manual, there is a section on LuaTeX that states:

> `babel`   *The `babel` package is not really supported!* Especially Vietnamese, Greek, and Hebrew at least might not work correctly, as far as I can tell. There’s a better chance with Cyrillic and Latin-based languages, however—`fontspec` ensures at least that fonts should load correctly, but hyphenation and other matters aren’t guaranteed. Under XeTeX, the `polyglossia` package is recommended instead as a modern replacement for `babel`.

What are the technical implications of this? Should I be afraid of anything?

Comment: What languages do you need?

Comment: Currently I don't need any languages (except German), I just want to know what this means. What is broken? Why is it broken? I want to be able to give an answer if someone asks me: "Can I use fontspec with Vietnamese and if not, _why_ not?"

Comment: And you don't like the answer "Yes, but you should use `polyglossia` instead of `babel`"?

Comment: @Ant no, because the _why_ part is what I am interested in. :)

Comment: @Ant: No, because polyglossia doesn't work (well) with LuaTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Languages that set an output encoding as part of their working in **babel** will have problems. For example, `\selectlanguage{vietnamese}` issues

```
\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont
\def\encodingdefault{T5}
\language\l@vietnamese
```

and of course the first two lines are nonsense with **fontspec** and OTF fonts. The same problem along with others will appear with languages written in other scripts (Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew). See, for example,
[Table of contents encoding issue with LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/tableofcontents-encoding-issue-with-lualatex).

Comment: Is this it? No more problems? Seems really easy to fix.

Comment: @Mateus: It shouldn't be very difficult but it could take some time depending on how much and in how many places the language files use and rely on some properties of the standard encodings.