# Parsing utf8 problems

Tags: macros, unicode, input-encodings

There are a number of questions relating to problems when using `utf8` input encoding, and the closest I found to my problem is, I think, [What characters in a normal text document will screw up LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38809/what-characters-in-a-normal-text-document-will-screw-up-latex/).

A user of my `censor` package asked if I can get the package's `\blackout` macro to work with `utf8` umlauts.  So far, the answer is "no".  I narrowed the problem down to the macro `\bl@t` which censors argument `#2` and then reinvokes a recursion via argument `#1`.  The problem, best I can tell, is that `utf8` encoding requires more than 1 byte for things like umlauted characters, and so the `#2` passed to `\bl@t` is only half a character, and so it chokes.

Here is an MWE that, if you uncomment either of the two commented lines, will break the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{censor}

\makeatletter
\def\stringend{$}

\long\def\blackout#1{\def~{-}\censor@Block#1\stringend\let~\sv@tilde}
\long\def\censor@Block{\IfNextToken\stringend{\@gobble}%
  {\IfNextToken\@sptoken{ \bl@t{\censor@Block}}%
  {\bl@t{\censor@Block}}}}

\long\def\bl@t#1#2{\if\bpar#2\par\else\if.#2\censordot\else\censor{#2}\fi\fi#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
äöüß, \censor{äöüß}\par
\blackout{ab\par cd}\par
%\blackout{ä}\par

\makeatletter
%\bl@t xä
\end{document}
```

The package's `\censor` macro works fine on the umlauted stuff, but `\blackout` and more specifically, the `\bl@t` service routine, do not.  If you want it more simplified, you can think of `\bl@t` as `\def\bl@t#1#2{\censor{#2}#1}` (but this will not work with `\par`s in the input stream).  The `#1` is always a reinvocation of `\censor@Block` on the remaining input string.

---

EDIT: It would seem that, if a multi-byte input character is next in the input stream, then this definition

```
\long\def\bl@t#1#2#3{\if\bpar#2#3\par\else\if.#2#3\censordot\else
       \censor{#2#3}\fi\fi#1}
```

can absorb it properly.  Thus, reversing which invocations are commented:

```
%\blackout{ab\par cd}\par
\blackout{äöüß}\par

\makeatletter
\bl@t xä
```

works fine.  So the key will be to be able to determine in advance which type of character lies next in the input stream and choose the appropriate parsing method.

Comment: Unicode characters indeed are more than one char (for pdfTeX). See @JLDiaz's nice answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86300/5049

Comment: You might be able to adapt my code here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34810/4427

Comment: @cgnieder So it would seem the approach should be to search somehow for the high bit set in #2.  If set, don't `\censor{#2}`, but set aside that byte, and wait for the next one in the input stream and then recombine them.

Comment: you don't have to look at the bit battern, simply the characters tex definition eg `\showö` will show `> �=macro:
->\UTFviii@two@octets �.` which tells you the first byte of o umlaut is the first byte of a two octet sequence (you could get three or four, depending on the character)

Comment: do you really intend `\if\bpar#2\par` ? `\bpar` seems to be `\endgraf` (ie `\let` to the primitove `\par`) so the effect is that any non expandable token other than a character is replaced by `\par`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\bpar` is a deprecated feature retained for backward compatibility.  If it shows in the user's input stream, it should be treated as a `\par`.  As far as `\if` vs. `\ifx`, I trust your interpretation better than my own limited understanding.  The purpose of `\blackout` is to censor the input stream one character at a time, making allowances for space tokens, `\par` tokens, and periods.

Comment: `\if` considers all (non expandable) commands equal `\if\par\vskip` is true. But even as edited it is not testing for `\bpar` in the input stream `\par` `\bpar` `\endgraf` etc would all test as true with `\ifx\bpar#2`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see.  In this case though, while converting a `\vskip` into a `\par` would not be ideal, I'm sure that `\censor{\vskip{...}}` would likewise not turn out well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want `\bpar` and `\par` to both test as true in that test, so what you have is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rather than worry about utf-8 it's probably best to let inputenc worry about that and expand all characters to LICR (latex internal form) then you would also be able to support `[latin1]` or anything else. I also changed `\if` it `\ifx` as `\if` looked wrong (although I don't really know what the code is doing:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{censor}

\makeatletter
\def\stringend{$}


\long\def\blackout#1{%
\protected@edef\tmp{#1}%
\def~{-}\expandafter\censor@Block\tmp\stringend\let~\sv@tilde}
\long\def\censor@Block{\IfNextToken\stringend{\@gobble}%
  {\IfNextToken\@sptoken{ \bl@t{\censor@Block}}%
  {\bl@t{\censor@Block}}}}

\long\def\bl@t#1#2{%
\ifx\bpar#2\let\next\par\else\ifx.#2\let\next\censordot\else\def\next{\censor{#2}}\fi\fi
  \next#1}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
äöüß, \censor{äöüß}\par
abcd, \censor{abcd}\par
\blackout{ab\par cd}\par
\blackout{ä}\par


\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that this works, but I'm trying to understand where LICR was invoked.  Is that the `babel` package that does that?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes LICR (latex internal character representation) isn't babel it is the basis of the latex `\protect` mechanism and in this case in particular of the way `inputenc` works.  add `\show\tmp` on the line after the `\protected@edef` to compare `\tmp` (which is what gets passed to your cancel code) with the initial input.

Comment: Ah ha!  It is the `\protected@edef` which does the conversion!  Got it.  Clever!

Comment: One final note:  Using your `\ifx` version of `\bl@t` breaks the code at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons/126358#126358, whereas using the `\if` version does not, so I think I will end up replacing your `\ifx` tests with `\if`.