# Why does XeLaTex mess up my em-dashes and quotation marks?

Tags: xetex, font-encodings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fontspec with Helvetica breaks quotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37855/fontspec-with-helvetica-breaks-quotes)

I'm using `XeLaTeX` with the `fontspec` package and `Adobe Garamond Premier Pro`. This works great, except that my `em-dashes` and quotation marks get all messed up. For example, entering `---`  (i.e., three consecutive hyphens) in the input file, I get three hyphens in the output file.

Ordinary `LaTeX` converted the three hyphens into an `em-dash` in the output file, as it should. Same for quotation marks: simply typing 'Text quoted' doesn't give me those nice curly quotation marks anymore.

I'm guessing it has something to do with font encodings, but being a total noob, I don't know what to do about it. Thanks for reading!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It should be `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Premiere Pro}`. Can you add the code you're using for selecting the document fonts?

Comment: Related: [fontspec with Helvetica breaks quotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37855/fontspec-with-helvetica-breaks-quotes)

Comment: @KimFierens We'll close this as a duplicate question of the one linked by cgnieder; this is by no means to be considered a critique of your question, but only an effort to keep the site as informative and concise as possible. We're waiting for other contributions from you (questions and, maybe, answers).