# Frequently loaded packages: Differences between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, packages, luatex

Adding the missing member to [pdfLaTeX vs. XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex) and [pdfLaTeX vs. LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-lualatex), here's the last of the big three: XeLaTeX vs. LuaLaTeX.

Where would a typical template for XeLaTeX differ from one for LuaLaTeX? Two areas coming to my mind in which it would be nice to get some detailed information on what's advisable to use, or what's currently usable to which degree with which compiler are:

1. `microtype`
2. `babel` vs. `polyglossia`

Since I don't expect there to be too many packages to list here, it might also sense to mention which packages *both* XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX users typically make use of, but *not* pdfLaTeX users, i.e. the common denominator (?) of the other two questions in the "trinity".

For the general differentiation between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX see [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36/4012). Also related: [Considerations when migrating from XeTeX to LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23598/4012)

Comment: @math folks: I'm not quite sure if "common denominator" is an appropriate metaphor here?

Comment: Some more related questions: [Drawbacks of XeTeX/LuaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3094/2693) and [What is the implication of the warning in the fontspec manual with respect to babel and LuaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30684/2693)

Comment: The main difference that I have come across between the two is how it handle fonts from `fontspec`. One example is that it seems that both have a different way of defining where to look for font, at least it is the case on my system, and although I have no problem using LuaLaTeX, I cannot make XeLaTeX use anything but the default font as it cannot find them (whether I use the font name or the font file name).

Comment: @ArTourter That sounds like something's wrong with your system, I've used plenty of non-standard fonts with XeLaTeX and `fontspec`.

Comment: indeed, managed to make the load by filename work with XeLaTeX. although the procedure when using opentype fonts from the TeX distro is cumbersome since all shapes must be specified. From the `fontspec` docs: _This technique is
also necessary in XETEX when loading OpenType fonts that are present within your
TEX distribution, such as /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/
public. Fonts in such locations are visible to XETEX but cannot be loaded by font
name, only file name; LuaTEX does not have this restriction._

Comment: One difference that I came across, is that I can specify the font style `SemiBold` in XeLaTeX, whereas LuaLaTeX requires `Smbd` (for exactly the same font).

Comment: Somewhat related: [availability of LaTeX packages' functionality in ConTeXt, XeTeX, and LuaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94438/14996)

Comment: @doncherry No problem at all. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 28):

While I’m no expert in either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, I’ve used both a bit, so I’ll try to write up some things that I’ve noticed in the “front-end” superficial user level.

### `fontspec`

... is the standard way of using fonts with both engines. I haven’t noticed remarkable differences in the outcome or font selection, but according to the comments to this question, there seem to be some.

This means, of course, that neither `inputenc` nor `fontenc` should be used. Do make sure to save your .tex file in UTF-8.

### `microtype`

Version 2.5 from 2013-03-13 seems to have improved XeLaTeX support a lot. For LuaLaTeX (and pdfLaTeX), protrusion and expansion are supported; for XeLaTeX it’s only protrusion. Since `microtype` typically works great without further configuration, you can simply load it for any of the engines.

### `babel`/`polyglossia`

`polyglossia` only works with XeLaTeX. A minimal setup of `babel` works with both engines (I think a recent update also included some improvements for XeLaTeX, is that right?), but the [package description on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) still says: “Users of XeTeX are ad­vised to use `polyglos­sia` rather than `ba­bel`.” Hence, I’d follow that advice and use `babel` with LuaLaTeX (and pdfLaTeX), but `polyglossia` with XeLaTeX. That’s certainly the way it used to be.

### `xunicode`

On up-to-date systems, this package should not be necessary at all – [that seems to be the verdict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3000/4012) here on tex.sx. If anywhere, it should only be used with XeLaTeX; in fact, it produces an error message in LuaLaTeX (unless it’s loaded after `fontspec`).

### LuaLaTeX-only packages

While there probably are some packages specifically tailored for XeLaTeX, I would assume there are (and will be) many more for LuaLaTeX, making use of the scripting language Lua being tightly tied into the engine. Two that I have used so far are [Patrick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243/topskip)’s [`lua-check-hyphen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-check-hyphen), enabling you to easily check all hyphenations that occur in your document, and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico)’s [`selnolig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) ([announcement on meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2884/4012)), which automatically suppresses typographically undesirable ligatures for English and German, based on an extensive pattern list. (Check [it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86606/4012) [out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108184/4012).)

Comment: It's not necessary to save your .tex file in UTF-8 when using ``fontspec``. I never do. My .tex file contains nothing but ASCII characters. I use macros for all non-ASCII glyphs. If you use fancy font-dependent characters in your .tex file, you're at the mercy of the display font when you visually inspect your file. That can cause issues when you open your file 10 years from now, and you don't remember what font you used, and it can be an issue when you share your .tex file with others (I've been at the receiving end of such files, much to my frustration).

Comment: @Sverre If you save a file in ascii it is automatically utf-8; so in fact you always do.

Comment: @phg I think we're talking about two different things here. I didn't say I save my file "in ascii", only that I use ASCII characters only. UTF-8 is backward compatible with ASCII, but you can easily save your file with something else than UTF-8 encoding and only use ASCII characters.

Comment: Regarding LuaTeX-only packages, there is also the new [TikZ graph layout library](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/drawing-graphs/).