# How to use the Calibri font

Tags: fonts

How can I use the Calibri font in LaTeX? I am using the following commands:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
```

I get the following error message:

```
!   Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
!   The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
!   You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"  
!   instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
!    See the fontspec documentation for further information.
```

Comment: The error message indicates that you should use XeTeX, LuaTeX or even XeLaTeX! I was once trying to do the same, but never managed to do so, without XeLaTeX. Which editor are you using?

Comment: i m using pdflatex. So far it is best for me.

Comment: Then you can't use fontspec and can't select the fonts which are only installed on your system. You have to stick to the fonts you install in LaTeX.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As others have pointed out in comments, to use system fonts (or any local .otf or .ttf font) easily, you need to use the `fontspec` package and compile your document with either `xelatex` or `lualatex`. `pdflatex` won't work, but switching to `xelatex` or `lualatex` shouldn't require any major change in your document other than converting to `utf8` encoding and removing any `\usepackage[...]{inputenc}`.

FYI, `lualatex` is the official successor of `pdflatex` in LaTeX3, and I personally see very little reasons not to switch asap to `lualatex`. If you want to read more on the differences, these links might provide you some more background:

- [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex)
- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-lualatex)
- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex)
- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87155/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-xelatex-and-lualatex)

Now, if you really can't / do not want to switch to `xelatex` or `lualatex`, and if you are *really* brave, you can stay with `pdflatex`, convert your Calibri font to Type1 and make it available to TeX. The tedious process is [explained here](http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm).

Comment: if i use lualtex, formatting gets changed. Everything looks unorganized and font still remain the same.

Comment: `lualatex` (not lualtex) should not change the formatting, and should change the font properly with the 2 lines you wrote in your question. Have a look at the log file for errors, and post another question if there is something else you don't understand. It's nearly impossible to help you without a MWE or your log file...

Comment: i have posted my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97288/lualatex-fontspec-font-not-found

Comment: The error message here is different, even when I compile with lualatex, the font is not found. I've downloaded the [Calibri font](http://www.cufonfonts.com/downloadFont/12048/calibri.zip) and installed on Ubuntu with a double-click. Any hint?

Comment: The [link above](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97288/lualatex-fontspec-font-not-found) has the answer, just create a folder in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` with all *.ttf files for Calibri.

Comment: Is this compatible with `latexmk`? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem and solved it in the following way:

1. Obtain your properly licensed Calibri .ttf font files. For the Calibri-family these are four files: Regular calibri.ttf, Bold calibrib.ttf, Bold-Italic calibriz.ttf, ItalicFont calibrii.ttf.
2. Place them in your OS's truetype font directory in their own folder. For Ubuntu the path would be "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/calibri/"
3. As [Xavier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96999/111805) mentioned you use LuaLaTeX with the `fontspec` package to specify the Calibri font family:

   ```
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont[Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/calibri/,
       BoldItalicFont=calibriz.ttf,
       BoldFont      =calibrib.ttf,
       ItalicFont    =calibrii.ttf]{calibri.ttf}
   ```

Comment: Note that if you have Calibri installed correctly in your system (see `fc-list`), this is not needed and you should be able to just do `\setmainfont{Calibri}` and it will choose all the correct variants. But this is useful anyways if you use e.g. Overleaf or have the fonts in the CWD not globally.

Comment: Also make sure that you add the trailing slash when supplying the path if using this method.

Answer (score 4):

When switching to `lualatex` or `XeTeX` is not an option, there is a metrically compatible font named *Carlito* that can replace Calibri.

There is the package

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}
```

that makes Carlito the default font.