# LuaLaTeX + fontspec: Font not found

Tags: errors, luatex

This refers to my previous thread [How to use the calibri font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96993/how-to-use-the-calibri-font). I am using the Calibri font with `lualatex`. MWE:

```
  \documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Calibri}
  \begin{document}
   The ends  of words and sentences are marked 
   by   spaces. It  doesn't matter how many 
   spaces    you type; one is as good as 100.  The
   end of   a line counts as a space.
  \end{document}
```

I am getting following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Calibri" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.3   \setmainfont{Calibri}
```

How can I avoid such error?

Comment: `\documentclass{...}` is better than obsolete `\documentstyle{..}`?

Comment: You are writing a LaTeX document, so you need to compile it using `lualatex`, not `luatex`.

Comment: I compiled using lualatex but i get following error message. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Calibri" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!..............................................

Comment: I edited my question after making changes as suggested.

Comment: Just checking, but as the error message suggests, are you sure you have the Calibri font installed on your system?

Comment: I am not sure, How to check weather it is installed or not?

Comment: @Aditya using LuaLaTeX did not work in my case, I needed XeLaTeX

Answer (score 12):

Calibri is a Windows font. If you have running Windows then it should be found by default, if present. Look into `c:\Windows\Fonts`

If you are running Linux then copy the TrueType files into your local `/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype/` or your personal `~/.fonts/Calibri/`. Then LuaTeX should update the font database by default.

You can also run `luaotfload-tool -vvv --update --force` then you'll see which directories were searched.

Comment: `luaotfload-tool -vvv --update --force` did the trick for me on Linux Opensuse Tumbleweed

Answer (score 3):

I faced exactly the same problem, with TexLive install in ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I found a way to tackle it.

1. Uninstall texlive (if you downloaded it from software center) and install ubuntu-tl. https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu (takes some time...)
2. Install windows fonts. Follow the instruction from here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2863497/how-to-install-microsoft-fonts-in-linux-office-suites.html

The following preamble is now working perfectly:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

For those using [overleaf](http://overleaf.com), mainly two things have to be done:

1. Select "XeLaTex" as your LaTeX enginge. This is described in point 1 of [this help page](https://www.overleaf.com/help/73-i-have-a-custom-font-id-like-to-load-to-my-document-how-can-i-do-this#.WwHUciAuDIU). For me, selecting LuaLaTeX did not work.
2. Upload the Calibri font files to your Project and write in `\setmainfont{CALIBRI.TTF}` in your TeX file. This is point 4 of [the help page](https://www.overleaf.com/help/73-i-have-a-custom-font-id-like-to-load-to-my-document-how-can-i-do-this#.WwHUciAuDIU). As a Windows user, I found the font files in `C:\Windows\Fonts` (Linux user should find them, according to [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97396/105520) of @Herbert in "your local `/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype/` or your personal `~/.fonts/Calibri/`")