# Custom font in Overleaf with pdfLaTeX compiler

Tags: fonts, pdftex, titlesec, overleaf

I am creating a chapter report template in LaTeX that will be used by others, mostly in Overleaf. There are requirements for fonts, etc. that are in a Word template that I am coding into a LaTeX template.

There are a few questions on StackExchange here about how to use a custom font in Overleaf. Many suggest using the XeLaTeX compiler which is too slow. I want to use pdfLaTeX.

Overleaf has instructions [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F#If_you.27re_using_pdfLaTeX_or_LaTeX) and [here](https://www.overleaf.com/project/61800a1dd7200c9a50af629b) on how to use a custom font with pdfLaTeX, and and answer to [LuaLaTeX + fontspec: Font not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97288/lualatex-fontspec-font-not-found) also has some tips, but I am still stuck.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% from Overleaf example at https://www.overleaf.com/project/61800a1dd7200c9a50af629b
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{fonts/calibri}{m}{n} #1 }}


\title{template}
\author{none}
\date{November 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\Huge\customfont{Custom Font Text!}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

**Project Setup**

[image]

**Current Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

1. I don't understand the missing number error. I am new to LaTeX and not sure what number is expected and where.
2. The text reads "n/24.88n/ ..."-- I expected it to read "Custom Font Text!" and be in Calibri font, not the default font.
3. Following text remained "Huge", and I expected it to return to the default

**End Goal**

I am trying to set the chapter and section headers to Calibri font, in Report document class, with pdfLaTeX compiler. I expect to use something like this in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\customfont\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
```

Open to suggestions on a better way to do this. Thank you

Comment: You can't just use TTF font files with pdfLaTeX directly. You need to convert them into a format that LaTeX understands. You can, however, use TTF font files with XeLaTeX and with LuaLaTeX. I would suggest that you browse through the relevant [packages on CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts) and chose a font you like, if you really want to stick to pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you, that is a much better idea. I ended up using [Carlito](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/carlito). If you write this up as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: David Carlisle did this already (and they added some more information about Calibri). You may just accept their answer.

Comment: note if you go `\Huge{abc} one two three`  all the text will be Huge to the end of the document, the syntax is `{\Huge abc} one two three`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note also that calibri isn't licenced for use off windows (unless you have bought it) you can use the chrome OS font clone carlito which uses the same font metrics as calibri and has already been set up for use with pdflatex with the `carlito` package.

https://ctan.org/pkg/carlito