# Is there a package/website with non-standard LaTeX Type 1 fonts (e.g., calibri)?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, truetype, arxiv

This question continues a question on using True Type Fonts with LaTex (exactly - `pdfLatex`) asked [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96993/how-to-use-the-calibri-font). As it follows from [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96999/23048), to use any True Type Font in LaTeX one should

- either use the `fontspec` package and compile the document with either `xelatex` or `lualatex`;
- or convert the `ttf` font to Type 1 and make it available to TeX (which requires considerable work).

Although the first option seems preferable, the resulting document compiled with `lualatex` becomes unusable for scientific purposes, as explained [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29580/23048). That means that if one wants to change the font, the second option is for now the only available for scientists.

At the same time, as mentioned in the same [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96999/23048), the process of converting a `ttf` font to a Type 1 one is rather tedious. It would then be nice to have a package or a web page with not all, but at least some other fonts already converted to Type 1 and readily usable in TeX.

My question is finally whether such package/webpage exists created by those who succeeded in conversion (`Google` showed none)? Or no one has ever succeeded??

I understand that there may exist copyright issues for some fonts (which would hamper the creation of such a package for them), but it should not be the case for all the fonts.

Comment: You don't need to convert the fonts to type 1, pdflatex can use ttf fonts, also such a conversion is rather easy e.g. with fontforge. But you must create `tfm` and other helper files - and this is the tedious part. See e.g. http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2008-November/007910.html. If you are looking specifically for calibri I can't help you. For other fonts I would check CTAN. Various new fonts have been uploaded lately.

Comment: Also, don't overgeneralize. Arxiv ≠ science. You can use ``xelatex`` and ``lualatex`` and still be a scientist.

Comment: If you are sending to ArXiv or indeed any other journal then you presumably shouldn't be messing about with non-standard fonts at all: is there more context here?

Comment: @Sverre Don't take it litterally. We all know that LaTeX ≠ science as well. By the way, do you know any scientitfic journal accepting xelatex or lualatex usage?

Comment: @JosephWright You are right about journals. But I just wish to have the same LaTeX workflow for journal submissions, arXiv articles and other usages. To keep it simple, you know.

Comment: Having calibri may just be modern: half of the modern documents are typeset with this font...

Comment: It is not hard to prepare the files to use truetype fonts with pdfLaTeX. (Or non-standard type1 files.) Just tedious. The Font Installation Guide is very, very good. Also, some packages include the files used to create them, sometimes with a `Makefile` and/or script and/or instructions. These make good examples (generally for type1 but truetype are not significantly different once you've generated `.afm` files).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`otftotfm`](http://www.lcdf.org/type/otftotfm.1.html) software to convert `.ttf` fonts to the necessary TeX font files.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I have found out that a good collection of LaTeX fonts can be found [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). The links to CTAN and installation recommendations are also provided. Apparently, it will be hard to find the *Calibri* font on the Internet since it is a proprietary one, but other similar fonts can be found on the web-catalogue mentioned above.