# Requested fontspec font not used, and no message in the logs

Tags: fontspec

I am trying to use Calibri in a beamer presentation, as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96999/14277). Everything seems to go fine, but in the PDF the font is `LMSans`. I can see the embedded font by looking up the fonts properties in Adobe reader, or by opening the PDF in a text editor.

I am running TexStudio and MikTex on Windows, the family of Calibri.ttf files are in both `C:\Windows\Fonts` and `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-font-truetype-calibri_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.0_none_fbba0686289345e3`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Looking in the log file it appears that Lualatex is loading both the Calibri files and the LMSans files from MikTex:

```
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg")(load luc: C:/Us
ers/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmsans10-bo
ld.luc)(load luc: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generi
c/fonts/otl/lmsans10-oblique.luc)))(load luc: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Mi
KTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/calibri.luc)(load luc: C:/Users/username
/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/calibriz.luc)(load luc
: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/cali
brib.luc)(load luc: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/gene
ric/fonts/otl/calibrii.luc)
```

Later on only mentions LMSans, not Calibri:

```
(./MWE.nav)(load luc: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9
/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmsans8-regular.luc)(load luc: C:/Users/username
/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmsans17-regular.luc)(
load luc: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/
otl/lmsans12-regular.luc) (./MWE.aux))
```

Comment: Since beamer defaults to sans serif, use `\setsansfont` rather than `\setmainfont`.

Comment: That simple huh, amazing! Thanks @Thérèse. Would you care to turn that into an answer?

Comment: I would, except that I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.  No time to hunt the other version down right now.  Another thing you can do, if you want to stick with `\setmainfont`, is add `\usefonttheme{serif}`.

Comment: @craq It is very appreciated that the OP finds that his/her question is a duplicate. Now, as your problem is solved and your question is a duplicate, you should delete/close your question.