# calibri recompile time error

Tags: fonts, fontspec, compiling

I would like to use Calibri in my LaTeX document. As this is not one of the basic fonts, I downloaded the Calibri package for Windows and added it to my file path (see picture).

[image]

Following the answers in this thread : [How to use the Calibri font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96993/how-to-use-the-calibri-font) I changed the compiler to lualatex and added the following code:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
BoldItalicFont=calibriz.ttf,
BoldFont      =calibrib.ttf,
ItalicFont    =calibrii.ttf]{calibri.ttf}
```

This results in the following error: "Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams."

Without the above code the file is not in Calibri, but compiles in only a couple seconds.

Comment: Try with small document using only `calibri.ttf` and not directly with your main document.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx!

Comment: note that the licence on the font doesn't allow it to be copied off windows, you should probably use a clone such as carlito.

Answer (score 1):

Following the guide on overleaf [I have a custom font I'd like to load to my document. How can I do this?](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F) this code compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{calibri}[ 
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldItalicFont=*z.ttf,
    BoldFont      =*b.ttf,
    ItalicFont    =*i.ttf
]

\begin{document}
text \textbf{bold} \textit{italic} \textbf{\textit{bolditalic}}
\end{document}
```

(However, it did also time out three times before it worked for me, at first... Subsequent compiles seem to work fine.)