# How to use / importing Calibri font into Overleaf with LuaLaTeX compiler

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, overleaf

I'm trying to get a Calibri font to work on Overleaf for the entire document with the LuaLaTeX as the compiler. I'm a bit new to LuaLaTeX.

Currently, I have defined a folder, called Fonts, which has the uploaded Calibri font files as .ttf extension.

The folder contains: CALIBRI.TTF, CALIBRIZ.TTF, CALIBRIB.TTF, CALIBRII.TTF, CALIBRIL.TTF, and CALIBRILI.TTF.

Then I added the following code, from [How to use the Calibri font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96993/how-to-use-the-calibri-font)
:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}     
\setmainfont[Fonts/,
    BoldItalicFont=Fonts/CALIBRIZ.TTF,
    BoldFont      =Fonts/CALIBRIB.TTF,
    ItalicFont    =Fonts/CALIBRII.TTF]{CALIBRI.TTF}
```

I'm getting a font to display; however, I'm also getting a few error messages and the text is corrupted.

Error:

```
1:
Package fontspec Error: The font "CALIBRI" cannot be found.

2:
Font \TU/CALIBRI.TTF(0)/m/n/12=[CALIBRI.TTF]:mode=node;language=dflt;+tlig; at enter code here
12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.17 
   
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

The last one is repeated couple times for the other fonts.

Below is a picture of how the PDF currently looks:

[image]

Any Ideas how to fix this font and the error message?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Try adding `Path=` in front of the first `Fonts/` and remove the other three instances of `Fonts/`.

Comment: Note that Calibri isn't usually licenced for use away from windows, and overleaf uses linux, You can use the Google `Carlito`  font which is metric compatible with Calibri and already available in Overleaf so you simply need `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Carlito}
`