# Why do I get this error when using babel?

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, errors, babel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\tableofcontents encoding issue with lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/tableofcontents-encoding-issue-with-lualatex)

I tried adding babel package to my file - to get proper hyphenation for my language. But I get strange error, related specifically to `\tableofcontents` (everything else is working, and hyphenation behaves as expected).

The test case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

The output:

```
$ xelatex file.tex
Package babel Warning: No input encoding specified for Russian language on inpu
t line 136.

)) (./TZ_Parrot_6.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\contentsname ->{\cyr \CYRS 
                            \cyro \cyrd \cyre \cyrr \cyrzh \cyra \cyrn \cyri...
l.5 \tableofcontents
```

How can I fix it? I'm using TeX Live 2009 distribution.

Comment: This seems very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/tableofcontents-encoding-issue-with-lualatex (that's `lualatex` oriented, but the problem is the same). If it solves your problem, with the caveat that `EU1` is the default encoding for XeLaTeX/`fontspec` rather than `EU2`, then let us know and this will be closed as a duplicate. On the other hand, probably `polyglossia` is better suited to XeLaTeX than `babel`.

Comment: @egreg - Yes, replacing `babel` with `polyglossia` fixed the issue, thanks! Should I delete the question?

Comment: I'll flag it as duplicate